# Encoding issue R LSA

Tags: r, lsa

dosen't lsa in r support foreign language

**my code**

```
library("lsa") 
Loading required package: SnowballC
trm = textmatrix("s/")
```

**the error**

```
[lsa] - could not open file s/s.txt due to encoding problems of the file.
```

or am doing something wrong

the file which produces error is the source page of [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005JBISDQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try loading the file up in something like Notepad++, then save it as a different encoding. There are also utilities that will convert it, I use one in Git-bash sometimes called iconv. You have to install Git to get access to it.

Comment: But it does show this error for other file from amazon this file contains é character